# tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab) doesn't call listener

Tags: java, javafx, listener

I have been [reading this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21022961/11092636). And they say `tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab)` will not trigger the listener on the event closing the tab which makes sense.

Therefore, I have applied their solution to my problem (I understand the principle, but not really the code), but my listener will never get called. Neither `tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab)` nor `closeTab(tab)` with the method `closeTab` defined like so:

```
private void closeTab(Tab tab) {
        EventHandler<Event> handler = tab.getOnClosed();
        if (null != handler) {
            handler.handle(null);
        } else {
            tab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(tab);
        }
    }
```

call my listener. My listener is however called when I do close the tab with the mouse.

Here is my listener:

```
private static void addListenerOnClosingTab(Tab tab) {
        tab.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<Event>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event arg0)
            {
                Util.loggerControllerDiagram.info("Tab " + tab.getText() + " closed.");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] please, demonstrating why you are using such an unusual construct - a onClose handler is notified automatically, if not null

Comment: If you want to respond to a tab being closed either by the user, or programmatically, why not just add a listener to the tab pane’s list of tabs?

Comment: Not sure what unusual construct you're talking about. I've just copied the other stackoverflow answer?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by a listener to the tab pane's list of tabs? sorry I'm a total beginner in java & javaFX.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows `tabPane.getTabs()` returns an observable list of the tabs in the tab pane. Add a `ListChangeListener` to it. I don’t really know how to say it more simply than that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to use `getOnCloseRequest` instead of `getOnClosed` in your method `closeTab`:

```
EventHandler<Event> handler = tab.getOnCloseRequest();
handler.handle(null);
tab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(tab);
```

Comment: That works very well, thank you so much. I don't really understand why handler.handle takes `null` as an argument though?

Comment: And why is there not the `if statement` that was in the other stackoverflow post?

Comment: I don't know why there was an if statmeent but doesn't matter what argument you'll pass to handler.handle because when you wrote the method you didn't use the argument anyway

Answer (score 1):

None of these approaches (in other current answers in this post, or in the original post you linked) really make sense to me. It's possible I am not understanding what you are trying to do.

If you want to respond to a tab being removed, whether it is removed by the user clicking the tab close button, or programmatically by manipulating the tab pane's list of tabs, the usual approach would be to register a listener with the list of tabs:

```
private TabPane tabPane ;

// ...

tabPane.getTabs().addListener((Change<? extends Tab> c) -> {
    while (c.next()) {
        if (c.wasRemoved()) {
            for (Tab tab : c.getRemoved()) {
                System.out.println("Tab " + tab.getText() + " closed.");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand your idea but I have this error: https://i.imgur.com/Z00yKgF.png. I guess the difference with the other posts/comments is that the listener is not on the list but that there is a EventHandler on each of the tabs? Still not sure what handler.handle does though. So if I can make your solution work, I'll be more satisfied as it is more understandable.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows  It should have been `c.next()` (I edited the code to fix it).